# Python asyncio collect info from multiple tasks at timeout, then continue in parallel to main until all tasks finished

Tags: python, python-asyncio

My use case:

1. I want to run N tasks in parallel
2. After a specific period (timeout) I need to know the results from the tasks already finished by then. This is my "main" thread. This is already working in the snippet below.
3. In a task parallel and independent to main, I want to continue waiting for the remaining tasks to finish. Onces all tasks finished successfully I need to do some calculations based on all N results, and store the computation in a persistent cache. "main" does not need to wait it.

Any hints on how to achieve no. 3?

```
        tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(self.call_111(harmonized_address)),
            asyncio.create_task(self.call_222(harmonized_address)),
            asyncio.create_task(self.call_333(harmonized_address)),
            asyncio.create_task(self.call_444(harmonized_address))
        ]
        await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=timeout.total_seconds())

        res = []
        for t in tasks:
            try:
                r = t.result()
            except asyncio.InvalidStateError as e:
                res.append(None)
            except Exception as e:
                res.append(e)
            else:
                res.append(r)
```

**Update:** (3) probably needs a bit more context. We are using python to develop AWS lambda functions. Our lambda function **must** respond within a given timebox, and it is acceptable for it to be a partial one. But we also want to wait for the remaining tasks to finish to update a cache with the full response.

Python based AWS Lambdas are not async. Maybe I need to start a separate thread, and execute the loop and tasks in their (similar to how larks outlined it in his answer below). And combine it with what [dmfigol](https://gist.github.com/dmfigol/3e7d5b84a16d076df02baa9f53271058) has posted in a gist about "Python asyncio event loop in a separate thread "

Obviously the new thread will finish later then the "lambda". I hope that is supported by AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the update; that's important information. I'm not familiar with AWS lambda myself; your proposed solution sounds reasonable assuming that the process persists after the response has been delivered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your questions correctly, so please let me know if this isn't what you were looking for. The following code runs a series of concurrent tasks. It waits up to a specific timeout for some tasks to complete, at which time it returns any results that have been collected so far. At some point later, a second call is made that collects the results for any tasks that did not finish before the timeout.

We take advantage of the fact that `asyncio.wait` returns the tuple `done,pending` (where `done` is a list of tasks that completed before the timeout, and `pending` is the list of tasks that are still running).

```
import asyncio
import random


class AsyncExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []

    async def example_task(self, id: int):
        sleeptime = random.randint(1, 20)
        print(f"start task {id}, sleeptime={sleeptime}")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 20))
        print(f"end task {id}")
        return (id, sleeptime)

    async def start_tasks(self):
        tasks = []
        for x in range(10):
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(self.example_task(x)))

        done, self.tasks = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=10)

        res = []
        for t in done:
            res.append(t.result())

        return res

    async def collect_tasks(self):
        res = []
        done, _ = await asyncio.wait(self.tasks)
        for t in done:
            res.append(t.result())

        return res


async def main():
    app = AsyncExample()
    res = await app.start_tasks()
    print("processing early results")
    for i in res:
        print("got early result:", i)

    # ... do something else...
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    print("processing additional results")
    for i in await app.collect_tasks():
        print("got late result:", i)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Running this will produce output something like:

```
start task 0, sleeptime=3
start task 1, sleeptime=17
start task 2, sleeptime=10
start task 3, sleeptime=12
start task 4, sleeptime=20
start task 5, sleeptime=15
start task 6, sleeptime=19
start task 7, sleeptime=15
start task 8, sleeptime=4
start task 9, sleeptime=6
end task 5
end task 8
end task 6
processing early results
got early result: (8, 4)
got early result: (6, 19)
got early result: (5, 15)
end task 3
end task 1
end task 0
end task 2
end task 9
gathering additional results
end task 4
end task 7
got late result: (3, 12)
got late result: (9, 6)
got late result: (1, 17)
got late result: (0, 3)
got late result: (4, 20)
got late result: (7, 15)
got late result: (2, 10)
```

Comment: That is definitely a very good start. I've updated the question to clarify the misleading part.